# rtmpdump compile without root, librtmp.so.1 => not found

Tags: compiling, non-root-user, shared-library

So I have successfully compiled it to `~/.local` by editing the prefix option in the makefile to `prefix=~/.local` the program compiles fine, and I did the same with `librtmp`. When running `ldd` on the binary I get the following output:

```
ldd rtmpdump-ksv/rtmpdump
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffedb4d2000)
librtmp.so.1 => not found
libssl.so.1.0.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007fc7489a5000)
libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007fc7485ac000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fc748395000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fc748113000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fc747d87000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fc747b83000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fc748c15000)
```

And I have tried to copy `ibrtmp.so.1` and `librtmp.so` to every directory in `~/.local`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programs do not search for libraries in the same directory as the executable by default. The traditional directory organization under Unix has executables in directories called `…/bin` and libraries in directories called `…/lib`.

if you set `prefix=~/.local` when compiling software, you'll end up installing the executables in `~/.local/bin` and the libraries in `~/.local/lib`. To tell the system about these libraries, add the following lines to your `~/.profile`, or otherwise arrange to set the environment variables `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

```
PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/.local/lib
```

On OSX, use `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` instead of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

What is your distribution? Does your distribution have `rtmpdump` available as a binary package? Debian does, for example, and therefore Ubuntu and Mint should as well, for example. If so, why aren't you using it? In any case,

```
apt-file search librtmp.so

librtmp-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librtmp.so
librtmp0: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librtmp.so.0
librtmp1: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librtmp.so.1
```

So, try installing `librtmp-dev`, if it is available. That might satisfy your missing dependency.

In general, first check for existing binary packages in your distribution before compiling and installing software locally.

Comment: I do not have root.

Comment: @pyCtrl_ well, you are going to have a lot of difficulty adminstering this machine without root. And you should have mentioned it earlier. Can't you ask whoever it is that has root to install these packages for you? And you still have not said what your distribution is.